# Is there an easier method to use a navigation menu with in each page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

So basically I've been working on my graduation project and I'm working on a website, of course the website has a navigation menu on each page of the website, the thing is that when ever I need to change something in the navigation menu it becomes a hassle going through each page to change something up.. my question is, is there a method like placing this nav menu in a function and displaying it? and if i do place it in a function how do i change the class to active with in each page?

Answer (score 0):

The best option would be to split it in templates (I would recommend using [twig](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but you can also [roll your own](http://chadminick.com/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html)). That way you would only have "navigation" on one file, which is the used by all others.

As for "which part is active", that would be done by passing a parameter in the template. The template should use that variable to determine, which menu item to show as "active".